# Word for the distance from the waterline to the main deck of a boat

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

What is the word for the distance from the waterline to the main deck of a ship? In other words, the height of the main deck (or gunwale if that has a name) above the water when the ship is at sea.

To understand my motivation, broadly speaking I am interested in the furthest you would fall if you were standing on the main deck and went overboard.

The distance from the waterline to the bottom of the boat is called the draught.

Comment: - Air Draft is the distance from the water line to the highest point on a ship (including antennas) while it is loaded. Technically, standard draft is the distance a ship can pass over, air draft is the distance a ship can pass under. 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_measurements

Comment: @user3850720, that sounds like an answer.

Comment: @user3850720 - Air Draft _includes_ antennas, whereas the OP wants the height _excluding_ masts, antennas, etc.

Comment: @Greenonline - yes, and I didn’t post that as an answer, but still worth a post here, I think.

Comment: @user3850720 It is helpful, if only to stop people mistakenly posting it as an answer.

Comment: It sounds like perhaps you are already thinking of a specific word in some another language, and are looking for an English equivalent?  If so, it would be helpful for reference (and interesting) to tell us the original word+language you have in mind.

Comment: @PLL Actually no. In fact I wanted to look up this value for different navy ships and had no idea what the term was to search for.

Comment: Could you edit the question to be clearer about what you're actually looking for? Your first two sentences contradict: the first asks (roughly) for the height of the gunwale above the waterline but the second asks for the height of the top of the superstructure above the waterline. In a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/448515/word-for-the-distance-from-the-waterline-to-the-top-of-the-hull-of-a-boat#comment1079335_448517), you say you want the distance somebody would fall if they went overboard but that depends entirely on where they fall from.

Comment: What's wrong with "topsides?"

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the "main deck" exactly? On ships I have been on recently there is a boarding point (fairly near the waterline) but the "main deck" is usually somewhat higher, which is where you go to admire the view. Do you mean "the lowest deck from which it is possible to fall into the water", or "the deck where most people stand during the voyage"?

Comment: @NickGammon I don't have a precise definition but had read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_deck

Answer (score 74):

The word you are looking for is *freeboard*:

> In sailing and boating, a vessel's freeboard is the distance from the waterline to the upper deck level, measured at the lowest point of sheer where water can enter the boat or ship.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeboard_(nautical))

Comment: _where water can enter the boat_ This is the essential point. All the words used to describe things on boats sound unusual to land-lubbers because they are very precise. The _freeboard_ is how far the water has to come up the side before you start taking on water. The _air draft_ is how much clearance you must have when going under a bridge. The _draught_ is how deep the water must be before you hit the bottom. All the terms have a precise meaning because they have a precise purpose.

Comment: The question is very explicit about wanting the distance to the top of the _hull_, not the superstructure - isn't it?

Comment: @Useless Yes exactly. In fact what I really wanted to know was how far you would fall if you went overboard, which is the same thing.

Comment: Well, unless you're falling from a fo'c'sle, poop or other deck raised above the lowest point of of the top of the hull.

Comment: @Useless True. I should say I have completely failed to find this freeboard figure for any navy ship so far despite now knowing the correct term.

Comment: @Anush I searched the web for "USS Enterprise freeboard" and found it on the third hit: "***Freeboard – height from flight deck to water**: 60 feet*". Here's the link: http://www.kartonmodellbau.de/WebRoot/Store3/Shops/63481486/MediaGallery/files/300101/USS_E_16_appendix_1_to_4_Enterprise.pdf

Comment: @Useless Actually, the question contradicts itself -- it says both "to the top of the hull" and "height of the boat when it is in the water excluding masts etc". The former is (more or less) the freeboard; the latter is something like air draught, except that includes masts and antennae. But, since this answer does answer one version of the question, I was wrong to claim it's wrong, so I've deleted my comment.

Comment: @Anush That depends on where you fall overboard from. You could fall overboard from many places: the simplest would be to fall over the [gunwale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunwale), which is basically the wall around the main deck. But there are typically holes cut through the gunwale, e.g. to pass mooring ropes and, on a large ship, a person could easily fit through one of those. Or one could fall from a part of the superstructure, e.g., on a [ship like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_Oasis_of_the_Seas), where there isn't a continuous deck around the superstructure.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You have introduced me to the word gunwale, thank you. Is freeboard not approximately the distance from the top of the gunwale to the water?  How high can gunwales be?

Comment: @Anush Not all ships have gunwales, for example the USS Enterprise aircraft carrier does not have them on the main deck. There are lower decks that have rails or gunwales. The height of a gunwale can vary from ship to ship. Generally a gunwale should not end below the knees or it will just trip people. On sailboats with hiking or trapeze systems, there may be little to no gunwale on the sides, and a "gunwale" to prevent shipping water in the stern. The freeboard does not include the gunwale height, if I understand correctly. Most gunwales do not prevent shipping of water.

Comment: @Anush Approximately, yes, but there are often large holes cut in the gunwales for mooring ropes (see, e.g., [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mooring_(watercraft)#/media/File:Fougeuse-02.jpg)). The gunwales can be quite high at the front of large ships: for example, [here](https://www.dreamstime.com/editorial-image-deck-sailors-working-ropes-wearing-blue-overall-yellow-hardhat-blue-ship-mooring-operation-image46380765), they're taller than the people.

Comment: @DavidRicherby My understanding is that in some cases those holes serve two purposes, the other being to allow water shipped over the side to spill off the deck.

Comment: There is also the factor that the main deck of a ship may not be of the same height throughout. There are many smaller ferries whose main deck is lower aft than fore, for example, sometimes by several metres. I don’t think there can ever be a universally applicable word for what this question is asking for, unless there happens to be a word that specifically means ‘the distance you fall before you hit the water if you go overboard at any given point on any given sea vessel’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't have a precise definition but had read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_deck

Answer (score 0):

"the height of the boat when it is in the water **excluding masts etc.**" is not operationally useful.  It won't prevent water from entering and it won't prevent the boat from colliding with a bridge.  Hitting a mast on a bridge can tilt the boat which could let water in.

Freeboard is all about flooding the ship.  It's how high water can come up without water coming onto the deck and entering the ship, so freeboard is defined by the lowest point of entry of water. But that's not what you're asking.

Air draft of course is the ship's height above water, or how low a bridge it can go under.  Also not what you're asking.

I think you're looking for "Deck height above water" and I don't think there's a nautical term for that.

Comment: It's operationally useful if you're not near any bridges.